# angular2 elvis operator and bracket notation / object access by key

Tags: key, angular, square-bracket

So, let's say we got a simple object that holds a string for two different languages like
`welcomeText = {"de": "Willkommen zurück!", "en": "Welcome back!"}`.

The `welcomeText` is a property of `Texts` object that holds all texts and gets delivered asynchronously 
(so i need to take care of possible undefined values, hence the elvis operator).
Now, in my angular2 template i want to show the text based on a current selected language.
This is working (but not what i need):

```
..
{{Texts?.welcomeText?.de}}   // works, as well as {{Texts?.welcomeText?.en}}
..
```

What i want is this (since language can be changed):

```
..
{{Texts.?welcomeText?[language]}}
..
```

Unfortunately this results in an error:

```
EXCEPTION: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Conditional expression 
      {{Texts?.welcomeText?[language]}}
     requires all 3 expressions at the end of the expression ..
```

No idea how to fix this error. I'm just not sure if i am using it wrong or if it simply isn't intended to work like that. For the moment i use a simple workaround, but i find it to be somewhat ugly since i have a method call everywhere i want to display text:

```
..
{{getText('welcomeText')}} 
..
..
getText(name : string){
 if(this.Texts)
   return this.Texts[name][this.language]
..
```

Is this just the way to go or is there a way to do it the way i want, with the elvis operator?
Thanks a lot for any answers!

Answer (score 4):

I actually ended up using custom 'safe navigation' pipe, as in my case chain of null-checks and square brackets was getting way to long and Angular's `?.` operator wouldn't fit into `[]` constraint.

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { path } from 'ramda';

@Pipe({name: 'safe'})
export class SafeNavigationPipe {
    transform(propertyPath: any[], source: any) {
        return path(propertyPath, source);
    }
}
```

Where [`path` function](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/blob/master/src/path.js) does all the job - retrieves data at given path and returns `undefined` as soon as the path can not be resolved.

And can be used like this:

```
{{ [userId, dayIdx, shiftIdx, 'status'] | safe:usersList  }}
```

Where array items can be dynamic values.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem, and while the Elvis ?. operator was introduced in this thread: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/791 it is now closed, @lgalfaso suggested extending it to include ?[ and ?(

In my book it should support this, mainly because the workaround is a tedious thing to have to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easier solution for your case would be using a ternary operator, like this:

```
{{ Texts && Texts.welcomeText ? Texts.welcomeText[language] : '' }}
```

You could test it your path to desired value and wouldn't have to call a function to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

`{{(Texts.?welcomeText || {})[language]}}`

so basically you are saying "get me welcomeText or empty object" - this will always return an object. Then you can fetch any property.

Answer (score 1):

you can use it like `welcomeText?.[language]`

```
{{ Texts?.welcomeText?.[language] }}
```

Answer (score 1):

[**Angular 12.1.0-next.5**](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1210-next5-2021-06-09) ([**commit**](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/ba084857ea018a4a77cfc855f0276dcaa2a0c2fa)) includes support for safe keyed read expressions, so from this version we can just use it normally as we do for non-dynamic properties/methods:

```html
{{ Texts?.welcomeText?.[language] }}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have a feeling what you're trying to do here isn't actually possible there's certainly nothing about it on the [template syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html) page.

For what its worth I don't think there's anything actually wrong with the solution you've come up with, it's probably how I would have solved this problem myself.

**Edit:** It's also worth noting that the I18n and L10n features of Angular 2 haven't been implemented yet, I'd stay tuned for this feature to solve the problem